# How to change text color while Typing in autoComplete jquery/Ajax

Tags: javascript, css, jquery

I type in a text box which gives matched data(Autocomplete where things pop up if data is matched using AJAX) from the server but when I type something which does gives any matched data than that character should be red. Is this doable using jquery, I was thinking of creating a dom element like span and storing those invalid characters there and then appending it to the textbox, but still was having doubt whether this would work or not.

Answer (score 0):

Change the input fields color wit the following line; when appropriate:

```
input.style.color = '#F41';
```

Where `input` is the "textbox" that is field that is currently being typed in...

The following *jsFiddle* exemplifies the ability of changing the *input fields* text color ***(type the characters 'e', 'f' or 'g' to view the color change)***:

http://jsfiddle.net/S87DJ/

Comment: ,I've updated a bit of Xabderhi's code
@user695362,I wrap that in a funtion ,here's the address:
http://jsfiddle.net/S87DJ/2/

Comment: @Lanston I can't see your updates - you'll need to save it on `jsfiddle` and provide the link in the comment. Nonetheless, my example is only to exemplify that changing the color is possible...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a plugin like [AutoSuggest](http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/autosuggest-jquery-plugin). Have a look at the demo in the website. You can easily customize it as per your requirements.